# Getting these loop errors in basic Perl

Tags: perl

I have the following code in Perl. I am very new to the language:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $date = $ARGV[0];

my $symbols = ('A', 'B', 'C');


foreach $symbol (%symbols)
{
    my $print = "$symbol";
    print "$print";

}
```

Getting:

```
Useless use of a constant in void context at (line of %symbols)
and
Global symbol "$symbol requires explicit package name at ..."
and
Global symbol "%symbols" require explicit package. name at ..."
```

Comment: `my $print = "$symbol"; print "$print";` is better written as just `print $symbol;`

Comment: You can make use of perl's flexibility and use `print for @symbols`. Read the documentation for [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) and [`for` (`foreach`)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) to see how that works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using an Hash when an Array is all that is needed.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl


    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my $date = $ARGV[0];

    my @symbols = ('A', 'B', 'C');


    foreach my $symbol (@symbols)
    {
        print $symbol;

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

1) Your `$symbols` should be `@symbols`, since it's an array. Later in the `foreach`, `%symbols` should be `@symbols`.

2) The `$symbol` is not declared. Say `foreach my $symbol...` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring `$symbols` instead of `@symbols`, so it is putting that in scalar context and setting it to 'C'. Then you try to loop through a hash with the same name, which you never created. Remember, `$a` (scalar), `@a` (array) and `%a` (hash) are all different.

This is what you wanted:

```
my @symbols = qw/ A B C /; ## the same as ( 'A', 'B', 'C' )
foreach my $symbol ( @symbols ) {
    print $symbol;
}
```

Really quick:

```
my @symbols = qw/ A B C /; ## new array with three values
my $symbols = qw/ A B C /; ## new scalar that is the last element of the "A B C" list ($symbols = 'C')
my %symbols = (
    A => 1,
    B => 2,
    C => 3,
); ## a hash with three key/value pairs
```

Comment: "setting it to 3"? Nope. "new scalar that is the size of the "A B C" array"? Nope. $symbols in the original code gets a value of "C", not a value of "3". A list is not an array...

Comment: `qw/.../` in scalar context returns the last element of the list, not the length of the list.

Comment: It's not even a list. It's a bunch of scalars separated by the scalar comma. Perl doesn't construct any list. There is no "last element". There is only the rightmost element. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your foreach is looking at each symbol in a non-existent *hash* called `%symbols`, not your array `@symbols`.

```
foreach $symbol (@symbols)
{
    my $print = "$symbol";
    print "$print";
}
```

Comment: Wow. Talk about a flood! Go team!